# OpenCV Otsu threshold: different results on Ubuntu (openSUSE) and OS X

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, ubuntu, threshold

When using Otsu's threshold provided by OpenCV on several systems I ran into a problem: the very same video frame was thresholded in a different way. To be more specific, on OS X it provides adequate results, on the contrary when running code on the same video frame on Ubuntu (or openSUSE) it performs really badly.
Could anyone, please, suggest what can be a possible reason or how to solve such problem?

Comment: Are aware of RGB ,  BGR color system of different OSs?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi I am applying threshold to grayscale frames so I guess this should not be the issue. Coversion to grayscale is done by OpenCV. I stick to RGB2GRAY as BGR2GRAY gives bad results in both cases. What's more it's a medical video and it uses color only for a better visual perception